# webGL drawElementsInstancedANGLE with a starting offset on the Instanced Array

Tags: 3d, webgl

I would like to know if there's a way to invoke the drawElementsInstancedANGLE() method in a way to not start drawing the first element of the Instanced Array, but a nth one that would be given.

It would be useful to render multiple ranges of transparent instances.

So far I saw nothing that could allow that, but, well, we never know, there might be a trick somewhere! :)

Answer (score 2):

There is not. Desktop GL has `glDrawElementsInstancedBaseInstance`, which does effectively what you want. But there are no [WebGL extensions](https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/extensions/) to expose this functionality.

However, you can always call `bindBuffer` and `vertexAttribPointer` for the instance arrays, providing an offset to skip some number of instances. It obviously won't be as fast as doing it with a `BaseInstance` call, but that's really all you can do.

Comment: thanks for answering, but can you elaborate, because I've looked at the declaration of both bindBuffer and vertexAttribPointer and I can't see what I could do to achieve what I want.

Comment: hello, ping, I would appreciate to have a clearer explanation because so far I can't figure it out